# In this sentence, should I use "hit" or "hits"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

In this sentence, should I use *hit* or *hit**s***?

> I threw a small stone, then I was worried about a car with a driver
> inside; if the stone hit the car, I would be miserable.

Comment: If you know that the stone did not in fact hit the car, then the most plausible answer is _...if the stone **had** hit..._ . You may have learned this as the _third conditional_. That said, I'm voting for migration to English language Learners where the question is a better fit.

Comment: You should edit the question to say why you think "hit" or "hits" and explain what you're trying to do. Also maybe relevant is whether you're aiming for casual speech or something in formal English with subjunctives and the like, because what I'd say normally may not match the grammatical construction you seem to want to use.

Comment: This contains the potential for a difficult elision [or omission]. One could easily say 'hit' whilst eliding/omitting 'had'. The only certainty is it would never be 'hits'.

Comment: @gone fishin' again. There's a special conditional variant, popular among football pundits, along the lines of "_If Salah hits the ball harder, the goalkeeper doesn't save it._"

Comment: @Shoe If I use "had hit" then instead of  "I would be miserable," should I use "I would have been miserable"?

Comment: @dsd. You don't have to. Use "_would **have been**_" if the incident happened a while ago and you think that you would no longer feel miserable. On the other hand, use "_would **be**_" if the incident was recent and you hypothesise that you would still feel miserable about it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to look at this, to put into context.

**(1) Events In Sequence** :: [ XX throw stone(s) XX ] [ very short time gap ] [ YY worrying about it YY ] [ short time gap ] [ ZZ stone(s) hitting or missing the car ZZ ]

At moment YY, you could say some something like this:

> **(1A)** I threw a small **stone**, then I was worried about a car with a driver inside; if the **stone hits** the car, I would be miserable.

> **(1B)** I threw some small **stones**, then I was worried about a car with a driver inside; if the **stones hit** the car, I would be miserable.

This is the Subject Verb Agreement Concept : Singular Verb with Singular Subject ; Plural Verb with Plural Subject.

**(2) Events In Sequence** :: [ XX throw stone(s) XX ] [ short time gap ] [ YY stone missing the car YY ] [ very long time gap ] [ ZZ talking about it now ZZ ]

Eg, XX was when you were a kid; ZZ is now you talking to a "Consultant".

At moment ZZ, you could say some something like this:

> **(2A)** This occurred ages ago, when I was a kid. I threw a small **stone**, then I was worried about a car with a driver inside; if the **stone had hit** the car, I would **have been** (and would still be) miserable; luckily, the stone missed.

> **(2B)** This occurred ages ago, when I was a kid. I threw some small **stones**, then I was worried about a car with a driver inside; if the **stones had hit** the car, I would **have been** (and would still be) miserable; luckily, the stones missed.

Even here, we have the Subject Verb Agreement Concept, but in the Past Tense, the verb did not change in this case.

Check :
https://study.com/academy/lesson/verb-tense-subject-verb-agreement.html

Answer (score 0):

Hit

What happened was, the "had" was omitted. The sentence should've been "if the stone had hit", or "had the stone hit"

the use of "s" suffix (I forgot the exact term for that) for he/she/it is specifically only for present tense.